# Fabric.js: Overwriting image via file upload

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Using fabric.js and a file upload button, I am trying to upload a second image file to my canvas. The first image is static and not to be affected by the upload button. The second image is to be constantly replaced by my file upload. It works the first time - the second image appears but when I hit the upload button a second time, using another image file, it won't overwrite it's predecessor. What am I doing wrong?

```
//file upload event
document.getElementById('imgLoader').onchange = function handleImage(e) {
    var file = e.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
        addImage(file.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}

function addImage(imgLink) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imgLink, function(img) {

        //second image already existing?
        if (canvas.item(1)) {
            canvas.item(1).src = imgLink; //does not work, image remains the same
            canvas.renderAll(); 
        } else {
            canvas.add(img); //works fine
        }
    });
}
```

I've been trying for hours and got the feeling I am missing just one tiny part. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function addImage(imgLink) {
    fabric.Image.fromURL(imgLink, function(img) {

        if (canvas.item(1)) {
           canvas.remove(canvas.item(1));            
           canvas.add(img); 
        } else {
            canvas.add(img);
        }
    });
}
```